# Pandas update column if other column does not equal specific string else nothing

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a pandas dataframe:

```
df
  Url_Sub_Fld   Url_Tld  MultipleExtensions  HTML_Encoded  contains_ip    ip
0 tel                    no                  yes           False          na
1 li                     no                  no            False          na
2 148.50                 yes                 no            True           191.88.148.50
```

I would like update the `Url_Sub_Fld` column based off of the ip column.  If `ip` column is NOT `na` then use the value in `ip` and update the `Url_Sub_Fld` column with that string.

Desired output:

```
df
  Url_Sub_Fld   Url_Tld  MultipleExtensions  HTML_Encoded  contains_ip    ip
0 tel                    no                  yes           False          na
1 li                     no                  no            False          na
2 191.88.148.50          yes                 no            True           191.88.148.50
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['Url_Sub_Fld']= np.where(df['ip']!= 'na', df['ip'], df['Url_Sub_Fld'])
```

**Output**

```
    Url_Sub_Fld     Url_Tld MultipleExtensions  HTML_Encoded    contains_ip     ip
0   tel     no  yes     False   na
1   li  no  no  False   na
2   191.88.148.50   yes     no  True    191.88.148.50
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach using boolean indexing:

```
df.loc[df.ip.ne('na'), 'Url_Sub_Fld'] = df.ip
```

---

```
print(df)

Url_Sub_Fld Url_Tld MultipleExtensions HTML_Encoded  contains_ip  \
0              0     tel                 no          yes        False   
1              1      li                 no           no        False   
2  191.88.148.50  148.50                yes           no         True   

              ip  
0             na  
1             na  
2  191.88.148.50
```

---

Or using [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
df['Url_Sub_Fld'] = df.Url_Sub_Fld.where(df.ip.eq('na'), df.ip)

print(df)
```